# Passing empty array to function - not working

Tags: c

I'm pretty new to C and am trying to do what I assume is very simple - but am getting stuck for some reason:

I have a `main` in a file called `runnable.c` where I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include "utils.h"
#define N 100000
#define num_vars 1

int main() {
    printf("I am running...\n");
    double values[N*num_vars];
    double ders[N*num_vars];
    char variable[] = "params.txt"; 
    read_file_to_array(variable, values); // fills up values 
    test_values(values);
    test_num_points(N);
    test_ders(ders);
    return 0;
}
```

I then have `utils.h` which defines

```
void test_values(double values[]);
void test_ders(double ders[]);
void test_num_points(int num_points);
```

And `utils.c` which has

```
#include <stdio.h>
void test_values(double values[]) {
    printf("I am in test_values\n");
}

void test_num_points(int num_points) {
    printf("I am in test_num_points\n");
}

void test_ders(double ders[]) {
    printf("I am in test_ders\n");
}
```

I'm compiling on my Windows machine using

```
cl runnable.c utils.c /link /out:program.exe
```

Everything works great when I just have `test_values` and `test_num_points` - but for some reason it doesn't run successfully when when I add `test_ders` into the mix. It still compiles correctly, but nothing is outputed.

I'm having trouble getting the debugger to work on my Windows machine and was hoping somebody might be able to help me figure out what's going on.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't fill ders when you fill variable and values? I'm new to C as well, but I'm wondering if you need to initialize ders before passing it to a function.

Comment: What do you mean by "it all breaks"?

Comment: @Tordek I mean that it compiles but doesn't run successfully (i.e. doesn't output anything).

Comment: Stack sizes are usually pretty small, i.e. only a few megabytes. So you need to be careful when declaring arrays as local variables. `double ders[100000*1]` uses 800Kbytes, so that's a bit big for a local variable. You can declare with the `static` keyword, or move it out of `main` (i.e. make it a global variable). `static` and global variables can use all of the memory, so they can be much bigger than local variables.

Comment: You never put any values into ders[], and you never print any values from it, so I'm not sure what output you're expecting.

Comment: @user3386109 - Thanks so much! You saved me much debugging!

Comment: @LivingRobot Glad I could help! Cheers! I've re-posted the comment as an answer, since it seems to have been the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stack sizes are usually pretty small, i.e. only a few megabytes. So you need to be careful when declaring arrays as local variables.

`double ders[N*num_vars];` translates to `double ders[100000*1];` and will use 800K bytes (assuming a `double` is 8 bytes). So that's a bit big for a local variable.

You can declare with it the `static` keyword, or move it out of main (i.e. make it a global variable). `static` and global variables can use all of the memory, so they can be much bigger than local variables. You can also allocate the memory dynamically, e.g. using `malloc` or `calloc`.

Comment: another recommendation would be to heap allocate it